# LPT with VC++ under Windows 7 ERROR: "External component has thrown an exception."

Tags: c++, windows-7, lpt

i'm trying to use the LPT port with c++ under Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010

```
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
    _outp(0x378,00000000);
    int input=_inp(0x278);
}
```

but i'm getting this error

```
"External component has thrown an exception."
```

So how to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, LPT1 is, for all practical purposes, no longer supported in Windows 7, unless, **perhaps** if there is a physical LPT1 device known to the system BIOS.

However, you still have 8 logical printer ports, numbered LPT2 through LPT9, at your disposal.